# Pause initial parse function until others are completed

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

First post here, long time lurker.
I'd like to ask something about scrapy. It's my first time using it, I've managed to get it to work but I have some questions regarding the order that the Requests are getting handled.

I have a `for` loop that yields some requests to different links and calls another parse function to do some stuff there.

Is there a way to pause the first parse function, so that the yielded request gets completed first and then go on with the next ones?

```
    evenselectorlist = response.css('table[id="result_table"] tr.even')
    for evenselector in evenselectorlist:
        item = LetsgoItem()
        relative = evenselector.css('a[title="links"]::attr(href)').extract_first()
        item['url'] = response.urljoin(relative)
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(relative), callback=self.parse2,meta={'item':item},dont_filter=True)

    #do some more stuff AFTER the requests have been completed
```

For example, my `parse2` function checks the requested url for a specific html element, then if it exists, it updates a counter. I want to see that final counter after the requests are all done. 
Is there any way of doing this? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it, but it wouldn't be a good way of using `scrapy`. I would recommend sending the first request and then after its callback, send the remaining ones, something like:

```
    ...
    evenselectorlist = response.css('table[id="result_table"] tr.even')
    relative = evenselectorlist[0].css('a[title="links"]::attr(href)').extract_first()
    item = LetsgoItem()
    item['url'] = response.urljoin(relative)
    yield scrapy.Request(
        response.urljoin(relative),
        callback=self.extra_parse,
        meta={'item': item, 'extra_selectors': evenselectorlist[1:]},
        dont_filter=True,
    )

def extra_parse(self, response):
    yield response.meta['item']

    for evenselector in response.meta['extra_selectors']:
        item = LetsgoItem()
        relative = evenselector.css('a[title="links"]::attr(href)').extract_first()
        item['url'] = response.urljoin(relative)
        yield scrapy.Request(
            response.urljoin(relative), 
            callback=self.parse2,
            meta={'item':item},
            dont_filter=True
        )

    #do some more stuff AFTER the requests have been completed
```